# How to Write an Address in a Single Line?

Tags: punctuation, formatting, readability

Not sure about the punctuation and I am finding conflicting resources online. Also, any opinion on whether I should spell out "South" or "Street?"

Here's what I've got so far (not my real address):

> 4 S. State St., Suite 6, Penfield, N.Y. 14611

P.S. This is for an email signature and the footer of a website.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: US State abbreviations use two letter abbreviations with no periods. Otherwise, that looks fine. I sometimes use bullets • or pipes | to indicate line breaks when listing an address on one line.

Comment: @Davo Postal abbreviations are all-caps without periods, but those are not the only way to abbreviate states; *N.Y.* is a more traditional abbreviation, and you would use it in the same contexts as *Fla.* or *Calif.*, such as AP-style news articles.

Comment: @choster True. I was projecting that receiving postal communication was the reason for listing an address on a website.

Comment: @tkendrick20 This really isn't about English, but about formatting conventions for a locale— the address would be written the same if the body of your email were in Ukrainian, or Urdu. It should be formatted so that one can easily distinguish the various components, but the only rules that apply are those of your organization. I use middle dots (·) myself.

Comment: I agree, this question is pretty opinion-based. That said, in my opinion you want some kind of separation between elements other than just commas. Common solutions include middle dots (which come in various weights, ·•●, depending on your character set) as @choster recommends, or vertical lines (|). I'd probably put one or the other between "Suite 6" and "Penfield": **4 S. State St., Suite 6 • Penfield, N.Y. 14611** or **4 S. State St., Suite 6 | Penfield, N.Y. 14611**

Comment: @1006a I like the idea of the dots and pipes, but given my site's font it actually looks better to me with a ton of commas. Also, I have removed the periods from "N.Y."

Comment: You could try playing around with other characters; if you have a windows-based system you can look at them all in your font in the Character Map (in Accessories/System Tools—I imagine there's some Mac equivalent). You could try simple options like a semicolon or dash, or something more exotic like vertical dots ⁞ or a diamond ♦. You might also want to experiment with either removing all periods from abbreviations or spelling out all abbreviations, just so you aren't as cluttered with punctuation.

Comment: "Opinion-based?" Uh, no: [Postal Addressing Standards](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/welcome.htm)

Comment: It will be more elegant without abbreviations.

Answer (score 11):

For US addresses, the [USPS Look Up A ZIP Code](https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction_input) tool is definitive.

It renders standardized addresses without abbreviations for things like "South" or "Street:"

> 18455 S Figueroa St, Gardena CA 90248-4503

It renders suite numbers and the like sans punctuation as well:

> 1137 Huntington Dr Ste B1, South Pasadena CA 91030-4582

It may account for regional differences in rendering addresses, so try it with yours.

Comment: The USPS provides guidance as to how addresses should be printed on mailing labels— not how they should appear in email signatures or anywhere else. Regardless of what's on the envelope, it's unlikely a block form letter will include the recipient's address in ALLCAPS NO PUNCTUATION; it would be jarring.

Comment: @choster The OP stated "not sure about the punctuation and I am finding conflicting resources online." The USPS is definitive about form and punctuation; people can make their own decisions about capitalization (including not capitalizing at all, which designers often do).

Comment: @choster the reason to include a street address is so that people can send mail to it.  Given that, it is logical to use the form that the Postal Service specifies as correct.  It doesn't need to be all caps, though.

Comment: http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/

Answer (score 3):

A good rule of thumb is to consider the purpose of the address.  If you're informing someone of where something is, spell the address out in full:

"The university's campus, located at 3737 Wascana Parkway, Regina, Saskatchewan, is situated at the edge of Wascana Park."

versus if you wanted to put the address for contact purposes:

"Should you have any questions, please feel free to write to me at 3737 Wascana Parkway, Regina SK S4S 0A2."